# Create tables with many attributes in SQLite via Python - best way?

Tags: python, sqlite, oop, sqlalchemy, orm

for a project, I have to create a table with 51 attributes in SQLite via Python using ORM, so defining the tables as classes. Structure is like this table, but with y1-y50, which are similar.

```
class Train(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'train'
    #Name columns and attributes
    x = db.Column(db.Float, primary_key = True, nullable = False)
    y1 = db.Column(db.Float)
    y2 = db.Column(db.Float)
    y3 = db.Column(db.Float)
    y4 = db.Column(db.Float)
```

I could now just copy those yi variables, paste and adjust them. But is there a better way to do so? Should I define the variables by help of a for i in range() loop? What is the best way to approach this?

Thank you already!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
for i in range(50):
    setattr(Train, f"y{i+1}", db.Column(db.Float))
```

Comment: `for i in range(1, 51)` instead of performing an addition every loop

Comment: @gold_cy Not a bottleneck.

Comment: an unnecessary operation though